# Is there a way to profile elasticsearch serialization/deserialization?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to obtain documents from elasticsearch rapidly. Some of the queries take several seconds to get the results to the python client.

When I tried the to run same query with `_count`, the results are instant.

I know that we can profile the queries via the `Profile API`, but is there a way to know how much time it takes to serialize the results on the server and deserialize them on the python client?

Comment: The count API will only return... a count, while the search API will return actual documents. There are ways to improve that, but it'd be nice to know what your use case is and what you're trying to optimize. It makes no sense to measure a sub-optimal process/design.

Comment: The query is just simple boolean query. The problem lies in the result size, which is in some cases around 10000 hits. I tried filtering the result fields and _source, so that I return only what is necessary. I also tried using http_compression, but it was even worse. When performing the query, I monitored the cluster cpu load and it was negligible. The result set is approximately 5MB and the connection speed 10Gb/s, so we can rule out the transfer to be the bottleneck. That leaves the serialization/deserialization (maybe other steps). Are there any tools to measure serialization?